# DrawImage c# How to change colors to black-white into the top left triangle?

Tags: c#, drawimage

Here is my code:

```
public static void ReduceScreenshot(string fileName)
{
    var bmpSS = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    var gfxSS = Graphics.FromImage(bmpSS);
    gfxSS.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
       new float[][] 
       {
           new float[] { 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 0, 0},
           new float[] { 1.5f,1.5f, 1.5f, 0, 0},
           new float[] {1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 0, 0},
           new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
           new float[] {-1, -1, -1, 0, 1}
       });

    ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
    attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
    Rectangle abc= new Rectangle(-783, -383, bmpSS.Width, bmpSS.Height);
    gfxSS.DrawImage(bmpSS, abc, -783, -383, bmpSS.Width, bmpSS.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

    bmpSS.Save("ScreenshotGray.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

}

It's how it work http://take.ms/6tzvU. How should i change area from rectangle to triangle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure just which points shall set up the triangle but the code to restrict `DrawImage` to it should look something like this:

```
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    ..
    ..

    Rectangle abc = new Rectangle(-783, -383, bmpSS.Width, bmpSS.Height);

    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    // three points to make up a triangle
    // repeat the first one as one way of closing the path
    // use your own coordinates!
    Point[] p = new Point[] { new Point(12, 34), new Point(56, 78), 
                              new Point(90, 12), new Point(12, 34) };
    gp.AddLines(p);       // or AddPolygon
    gfxSS.SetClip(gp);    // now restrict the Graphics object to the interior of the path

    gfxSS.DrawImage(bmpSS, abc, -783, -383, bmpSS.Width, bmpSS.Height,
                     GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
```